# Roboletric can't make custom dialog visible

Tags: unit-testing, android-fragments, robolectric

I am trying to build unit-test case for a custom dialog that extends the Android DialogFragment using Roboletric but I hit a hard wall. Basically, the unit-test framework cannot make the fragment "visible"; therefore, I cannot test anything.

anyway, the code is pretty basic and based on this thread:

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

here's is my app code:

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public Dialog mCustomDialogTest;
    public EditText mEditText;
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mCustomDialogTest = new Dialog(getActivity());
        mCustomDialogTest.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mCustomDialogTest.getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        mCustomDialogTest.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        mCustomDialogTest.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        mEditText = (EditText) mCustomDialogTest.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);
        return mCustomDialogTest;
    }
}
```

the super basic custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/app_name"
        android:inputType="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally my unit-test:

```
@Test
public void testCustomDialog() {
    CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog();
    customDialog.show(mActivity.getFragmentManager(), getClass().getName());

    boolean visible = customDialog.isVisible(); //This never works :(
    Assert.assertTrue("Dialog is visible", visible);
}
```

It always asserts saying it is not visible :( Yet, the code works fine on the device.

Here are the relevant parts in the gradle:

```
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
}
```

Anyone can help me? I am totally stuck on the most basic functionally for the unit-test.

thank you!

Comment: for simpler solution, you can use some milliseconds of sleep before the customDialog.isVisible(). that should work.

Comment: I tried that before and it did not wok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the `getUserVisibleHint` method instead of the `isVisible` method